# Cloudant incremental backup supported?

Tags: cloudant

I was working on an incremental backup solution for my Cloudant databases.
I was using the documentation at https://docs.cloudant.com/backup-guide.html  and today I tried to go back to that link to look something up and the page is gone.

Is this an error in the documentation, or has support for this been removed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on the page you were reading was for features that have not yet been released. Once the features are officially released, we will make that page available again. In the meantime, this page may be helpful: https://docs.cloudant.com/backup.html